# How to get objects from txt file to use in javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, text

I am very new to coding and javascript; just a few days in. I was wondering if there was a way to import objects from a text file(separated by lines) to use in my array: `replyText`. Here is what I'm working with:

```
// Variables

var theButton = document.getElementById("theButton");
var mainText = document.getElementById("mainText");
var replyText = [...,...,...,...,];
var i = 0;

// Functions

function nextText() {
  mainText.innerHTML = replyText[i++ % replyText.length];
}

// MAIN SCRIPT

theButton.onclick = function() {
    nextText();
};
```

Comment: You can use `XMLHttpRequest()` to request file from server

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest` to get the `.txt` file just pass the path of it.

```
var file = new XMLHttpRequest();
file.open("GET", "file:/../file.txt", false);
file.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (file.readyState === 4) {
        if (file.status === 200 || file.status == 0) {
            var text = file.responseText;
            alert(text);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: you must pass the absolute path `file:///C:/your/path/to/file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

**For client/browser-side file reading:**

You cannot easily read a file on the client-side as you are *not allowed direct access* to the client's file system. However, you can place a `input` element of file type in your HTML markup via which the client can load a file for your program to process. For example:

```
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="readFile()" />
```

Now when the client selects a file for use, the `readFile()` function will be called which will read and process the file. Here's an example:

```
function readFile() {

    var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0]; // select the input element from the DOM

    var fileReader = new FileReader(); // initialize a new File Reader object

    fileReader.onload(function() { // call this function when file is loaded

        console.log(this.result); // <--- You can access the file data from this variable

        // Do necessary processing on the file

    });

    fileReader.readAsText(file); // Read the file as text

}
```

For more information on File Reader, check out the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Paulo's solution, read below for splitting string by line breaks (new line character)

```
var replyText = text.split("\n"); // "\n" is new line character
```